# psshutdown cant shut down windows 2008 Access is denied

Tags: window, remote-access, shutdown

I use psshutdown.exe to remote shutdown computers .

but for windows 2008 and windows 7, when I use psshutdown.exe, it has error "ACCESS is denied "

I use administrator username and password

how can I solve it ?

Comment: Go to 'Control Panel'-> Click 'Change account type' under 'User Account' Section -> Check if your account is local administrator or not. (Domain administrator is not the same as local administrator!)

Comment: the user I logged on is local admin . but this user can not shutdown other system remotely even I have system's local admin username and password

Comment: if i run this process in windows service . I have the same error

Answer (score 0):

try the following command:

```
shutdown -s -t 0
```

Comment: Save your work before running this command. You might want to read the `-help` section first.